# Sesiones en Flask

Tags: python, web, login, flask, sesiones

Buen día

Por favor su ayuda:

Al crear un aplicativo web ¿existen estas dos opciones de sesiones?

1. Que los usuarios usen el aplicativo teniendo acceso todos a la misma fuente de datos, es decir, si el *usuarioX* se logea y guarda un *archivoA*; y luego el *usuarioZ* se logea, este último pude manipular ese *archivoA*.
2. Que cada usuario que se logea tiene su espacio privado de datos, es decir, me refiero a que por ejemplo es una calculadora web, el *usuario1* se logea y hace una suma y guarda el resultado; al mismo tiempo el *usuario2* se logea y hace una división y guarda su resultado. Pero ninguno "invade" el resultado del otro.

Si es así, entonces al crear un "login" en **Flask**, ¿el resultado será la opción 1 o la 2?

Gracias por su amable explicación.

Comment: Depende de como tu montes tu sistema de Base de datos, puede ser de una forma u otra, no tiene nada que ver con Flask, tiene que ver con el desarrollo que tú implementes. Puedes hacer uno u otro, eso ya es a tú elección

Comment: Gracias, por favor, tal vez hay alguna referencia donde pueda profundizar respecto a lo que me indica? Sobre todo respecto a la opción para que hayan "repositorios separados" (no sé como decirlo técnicamente). le agradezco mucho.